# can't get value from html tag

Tags: html, angular

I'm trying to retrieve the value inside an html tag. I can retrieve the whole tag but not the value inside.

in app.component.html:

```
<p #docTitle>the thing I want to extract</p>
```

in app.component.ts

```
docTitle;

@ViewChild('docTitle') docTitle;

ngAfterViewInit(){
    console.log(this.docTitle.nativeElement.value); //this gives me the whole tag
}
```

i've tried

```
<p id="docTitle">what I want to retrieve</p>
```

with

```
document.getElementById('docTitle').value //same as above, gives whole tag
```

The point of this whole thing is to retrieve the value (which is translated in different languages with i18n) in order to use it to settle the html page's title.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
docTitle.getElementById('docTitle').innerText
```

or

```
docTitle.getElementById('docTitle').textContent
```

or

```
docTitle.getElementById('docTitle').innerHTML
```

`value` is for input elements

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
    console.log(this.docTitle.nativeElement.innerHTML);
    // OR
    console.log(this.docTitle.nativeElement.textContent);
}
```